# OpenShift validate pod memory and cpu before deployment

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We are deploying our service to OpenShift using Deployment Config, we specify resource limits in the yaml file.

We are using OC Process command from Azure Devops to deploy our service.

Looking for a way to validate if requested memory and cpu are available before deployment.

Is there a way to achieve this from Azure Devops or through some bash script that I can include in the tasks.

Comment: Are you using "[Azure Red Hat OpenShift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/openshift-get-started#azure-red-hat-openshift)"? (also referenced in "[Deploy an application from source to Azure Red Hat OpenShift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/howto-deploy-with-s2i)")

Answer (score 0):

It’s the kube-scheduler that takes charge of scheduling pods in nodes where the required resources are available.

> When you specify the resource request for containers in a Pod, the kube-scheduler uses this information to decide which node to place the Pod on. When you specify a resource limit for a container, the kubelet enforces those limits so that the running container is not allowed to use more of that resource than the limit you set. The kubelet also reserves at least the request amount of that system resource specifically for that container to use.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

I think inventing a script that controls these parameters on nodes is an anti-pattern.

What you should do is:

1. make a pre-assesment with n. pod provided + cpu/ram requests/limits
2. ensure that the Workers have enough resources for the expected load
3. add controls in Pipeline on Deployments requests/limits to make sure the released resources are what you expect
4. configure active monitoring to intercept when nodes saturate a certain level of resource usage (with the Prometheus/Alertmanager monitoring stack it is very easy to achieve this) and eventually proceed with a scaling of Nodes/Pods

Obviously if you have resources that don’t have to have limits, maybe to manage exceptionally peaks of resources or things of this type (I think to a Jenkins for example) it's better to have nodes dedicated to these only Deployments.

If the cluster isn't at your disposal, but maybe shared with other application teams, it is definitely a good idea to associate Quota on Namespace and/ or dedicate with Taint/ Tolerations of the Workers to your Project.

To get back to your script request, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

your_service_cpu=<INSERT HERE YOUR DEPLOYMENTS CPU LIMIT>
your_service_memory=<INSERT HERE YOUR DEPLOYMENTS MEM LIMIT>

for i in $(kubectl get nodes -l node-role.kubernetes.io/worker --no-headers | awk '{print $1}')
do 
  worker=$(echo $(kubectl top node $i --no-headers | awk '{print $1}'))
  cpu=$(echo $(kubectl top node $i --no-headers | awk '{print $2}'))
  memory=$(echo $(kubectl top node $i --no-headers | awk '{print $4}'))
#  echo $worker
#  echo $cpu
#  echo $memory
  cpu_int=$(echo "${cpu%?}")
  memory_int=$(echo "${memory%??}")
#  echo $cpu_int
#  echo $memory_int
  if (( $your_service_cpu >= $cpu_int ))
  then 
    exit 1
  fi
  if (( $your_service_memory >= $memory_int ))
  then
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

The script could definitely be improved.

PS: as mentioned above, I would avoid this approach.

Comment: Obviously a script like this can make sense before deployment, to understand the status of the cluster resources, but it doesn't give any added value to Kubernetes, because kube-scheduler already has this information.
It isn’t possible to dynamically tell the Scheduler where to put the resources except by adding parameters such as the nodeSelector... but doing this dynamically becomes really complex; remains an anti-pattern.